# Is 2x8 lumber suitable for window boxes in a poured foundation?

Tags: windows, foundation

We are about to have a new house built and the foundation is 8" thick. The foundation forms will be wood with metal straps. Finished boxes will be wood.

Will 2x8 pressure treated wood be good for building the window boxes and sills? These will be embedded in the foundation walls when they pour. The actual size of this wood is 7.25. Is this ok or should I buy 2x10s and rip them down to 8" exactly?

Comment: I have to ask... why is this something your builder isn't handling (or answering)?  Anyone building foundation forms must have an plan and experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could rip down 2X10s or simply add some scrap 3/4" material whether it is 3/4"plywood or 1X. It does not need to be PT, it can be removed after the pour if you choose to. My suggestion would be as well, to add at least 3" hot dipped, not electroplated nails around the outside perimeter to keep the PT frames from moving over time after everything shrinks. All will shrink, the wood AND concrete. A pair every 16" apart at least. You could use lag bolts too, but it is overkill.

Comment: If I read correctly, the nails should be partially driven into the wood, then project into the forms so the heads will be embedded in concrete?